# magento 2 product only show in category when changing pagination

Tags: magento-2.1

I have a products that doesn't show up in a category called "**News**". But when I change products shown per page from **60 to 80** it will show up. The product is number 7 on the list and therefore should be show on the first page and not first when I change to 80 products per page (see example of pagination drop down below).

I have tried **reindexing** and **flush cache** with no luck.

I use **Magento 2.1.8**

[image: pagination]

Comment: Have u check at pagination second page of pagination

Comment: Yes, that is not the problem. See my revised question.